# "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" when click selected kendo tree item

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I used Kendo-angular directive for Kendo tree view. I formed datasource using the following method and view as below. I don't get any error if use Jquery style instead of Angular directive.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource()
$scope.templateData = dataSource ;

<div kendo-tree-view="tree" k-data-source="templateData" k-on-change="onTemplateSelection(dataItem)"></div>

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    spriteCssClass: "sprite",
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    dataTextField:  [ "AppName", "Name" ],
                    select: onSelect
                });
```

Tree loads fine and on-change event fires when we click any item on tree. However, when we click the selected item again then change event doesn't trigger and it triggers error that reads.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Object.ve.proxyModelSetters (kendo.all.min.js:26)
    at init.<anonymous> (kendo.all.min.js:86)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.min.js:25)
    at init.select (kendo.all.min.js:59)
    at init._click (kendo.all.min.js:58)
```

Comment: Can you give us the content of the `onTemplateSelection` function?

Comment: $scope.onTemplateSelection = function (dataItem) {
            onSelect(dataItem, false);
    };

Comment: And the content of `onSelect`?

Comment: It has huge logic, however $scope.onTemplateSelection itself is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find the error without having all the code but basically the exception you're getting is quite simple. Somewhere in your code you probably have a block that looks like this:

```
if (object !== "null") { // The null is a string and not actually null
    ...
    Object.keys(object) ...
    ...
}
```

Search your code for 'null' or "null". if you don't find it like this, see if you might have misspelled it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. Once I clicked an item on the tree, I used to remove the class, k-"state-selected" from the item. Next time when I click the same item, it seems it uses the same class("k-state-selected") and data-uid to find the selected item. So as it was not present on that item, it used to give the error mentioned above.